# Leading and trailing zeros in numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am working on a project where I require to format incoming numbers in the following way:

```
###.###
```

However I noticed some results I didn't expect.
The following works in the sense that I don't get an error:

```js
console.log(07);

// or in my case:
console.log(007);
```

Of course, it will not retain the '00' in the value itself, since that value is effectively 7.

The same goes for the following:

```js
console.log(7.0);

// or in my case:
console.log(7.000);
```

JavaScript understands what I am doing, but in the end the actual value will be 7, which can be proven with the following:

```js
    const leadingValue = 007;
    const trailingValue = 7.00;

    console.log(leadingValue, trailingValue); // both are exactly 7
```

But what I find curious is the following: the moment I combine these two I get a syntax error:

```
// but not this:
console.log(007.000);
```

**1) Can someone explain why this isn't working?**

I'm trying to find a solution to store numbers/floats with the exact precision without using string.

**2) Is there any way in JS/NodeJS or even TypeScript to do this without using strings?**

What I currently want to do is to receive the input, scan for the format and store that as a separate property and then parse the incoming value since `parseInt('007.000')` does work. And when the user wants to get this value return it back to the user... in a string.. unfortunately.

Comment: "*The following works*" can you define what you mean by that? Because you don't get the number `07` or `007` in the output. The way it "works" is that it doesn't throw an error. And I don't know why you'd need to ever write `007.000` - that is apparently a syntax error (which, TBH, I didn't know until now) but more importantly, it's useless as you're *at best* going to merely get `7` out.

Comment: As 2) - you *cannot* escape the strings. JS numerics will only be represented how JS wants to. It doesn't capture the format you used, so `7` and `7.0` and `7.000` are the same value. That's true for any language I know of - primitives require separate formatting.

Comment: i guess this is only displayed without those `0`s. Internally it is still the same, but why don't just use strings? If you want to **display** the number a string is fine and it also makes no difference in calculating if you do `3 * 7.00` or `3 * 7` and so on...

Comment: Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal

Comment: @VLAZ tbh, I was just experimenting with what I can do and not and just encountered this one. I understand that in the end 7.0 will be treated as 7. I'm looking for a way to prevent storing properties like 'quantity' as a string value, since that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Kai then format on display. It makes even less sense to keep store a display format with *each* numeric value you have.

Comment: @Kai try `console.log(009.000)` and tell me what happens

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) `007.000` is a syntax error because 007 is an octal [integer literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers), to which you're then appending a floating point part.  (Try `console.log(010)`. This prints 8.)

2) Here's how you can achieve your formatting using [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)...

```js
var myformat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { 
    minimumIntegerDigits: 3, 
    minimumFractionDigits: 3 
});
console.log(myformat.format(7)); // prints 007.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi

You can use an aproach that uses string funtions .split .padStart and .padEnd

Search on MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Here you have an example:

```js
const x = 12.1;

function formatNumber( unformatedNumber) {
  const desiredDecimalPad = 3;
  const desiredNonDecimalPad = 3;

  const unformatedNumberString = unformatedNumber.toString();
  const unformatedNumberArr = unformatedNumberString.split('.');
  const decimalStartPadded = unformatedNumberArr[0].padStart(desiredDecimalPad, '0');
  const nonDecimalEndPadded = unformatedNumberArr[1].padEnd(desiredNonDecimalPad, '0');
  const formatedNumberString = decimalStartPadded + '.' + nonDecimalEndPadded;

  return formatedNumberString;
}


console.log(formatNumber(x))
```

Comment: this function will return a string that you can use on your frontend whenever you want to present the variable formated. you don't need to save the number formated in you backend (i think...)